# Record and play using Audio Queues in iPhone

Tags: iphone, audioqueueservices

Can someone explain how we can use Audio Queue services to record sound from Microphone and play it live? Explain how we can achieve it. If possible give code snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RemoteIO Audio Unit.  [This](http://atastypixel.com/blog/using-remoteio-audio-unit/) awesome code will get you on the right path.

Comment: Does RemoteIO use Audio Queue Services internally?

Comment: RemoteIO is lower level. It is basically the hardware buses that deal with audio. The important part of that page is the callbacks, where you deal with audio buffers.  In the write callback, you write the buffers to disk (not implemented there), and in the read buffer, you can process the playback sound in real time if you want, otherwise ignore it